# javax.sql.DataSource-Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pi4j

I'm a beginner and creating simple spring boot application with pi4j library, but i think have a problem with module-info.java. I don't know what's wrong. Is there a dependencies missing? I've tried different dependencies, changes in module-info.java, but nothing works. Anyone knows what's going on?
Traceback

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

[restartedMain] INFO com.example.myprojectraspi.MyProjectRaspiApplication - Starting MyProjectRaspiApplication using Java 16.0.1 on DESKTOP-KPH6U2Q with PID 13620 (C:\Users\Gwiazdorz\IdeaProjects\MyProjectRaspi\target\classes started by Gwiazdorz in C:\Users\Gwiazdorz\IdeaProjects\MyProjectRaspi)
[restartedMain] INFO com.example.myprojectraspi.MyProjectRaspiApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[restartedMain] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[restartedMain] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration due to javax/sql/DataSource not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:54)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:489)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:478)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at spring.context@5.3.9/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at spring.boot@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at spring.boot@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at spring.boot@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at spring.boot@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at spring.boot@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at spring.boot@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at MyProjectRaspi/com.example.myprojectraspi.MyProjectRaspiApplication.main(MyProjectRaspiApplication.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration$DevToolsDataSourceCondition.getMatchOutcome(DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:183)
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.5.4/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 25 more
```

Module-info.java

```
module MyProjectRaspi {
        requires com.pi4j;
        requires com.pi4j.plugin.pigpio;
    
        // SLF4J MODULES
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires org.slf4j.simple;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.web;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.transaction;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.security.config;
    requires lombok;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;

    uses com.pi4j.extension.Extension;
    uses com.pi4j.provider.Provider;

    // allow access to classes in the following namespaces for Pi4J annotation processing
    opens com.example.myprojectraspi to com.pi4j;
    exports com.example.myprojectraspi;

}
```

Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProjectRaspi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MyProjectRaspi</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
 
    <slf4j.version>2.0.0-alpha0</slf4j.version>
    <pi4j.version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</pi4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-snapshots-repo</id>
        <name>Sonatype OSS Maven Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${pi4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>

</dependency>



   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-plugin-raspberrypi</artifactId>
        <version>${pi4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-plugin-pigpio</artifactId>
        <version>${pi4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
<finalName>MyProjectRaspiservice</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${java.version}</release>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--module-path</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/distribution</argument>
                    <argument>--module</argument>
                    <argument>com.example.myprojectraspi/com.example.myprojectraspi.MyProjectRaspiApplication</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/distribution</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/distribution" overwrite="true" flatten="true">
                                <fileset dir="assets" includes="*.sh" ></fileset>
                            </copy>
                            <chmod dir="${project.build.directory}/distribution" perm="ugo+rx" includes="**/*.sh"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/distribution</outputDirectory>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shades
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
server.port=9090
```

Comment: It is probably easier not to use the Java Module System, as Spring Boot itself is not modularized either. The problem itself can probably be solved by adding a `requires java.sql;` to your `module-info.java`, but likely you will need to play whack-a-mole with all other libraries used.